# How do I execute a command as the original user from a sudo'd program?

Tags: c, unix, sudo

I have to use `sudo` to run my program:

```
 sudo ./my_program
```

I am trying to run `git clone` from my program, but it tries to use the root user's SSH keys  instead of mine.
Is there a way to execute this single command as the user who originally invoked my program?

I guess I can do:

```
su - original_user -c "git --version"
```

But how do I figure out the username of the original user?  Or is there another elegant solution this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`sudo`](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/sudo.man.html) manual shows that `$SUDO_USER` should give you the original user's username and `$SUDO_UID` gives the original user's UID.

Comment: And `$SUDO_UID` the original user's UID.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Samba on a NAS while creating files from a web-application.

In this case I retrieved the running processes and determined which user was running samba.
After isolating that name, I had the correct user account. Maybe this will work for your situation as well?

In this case I imagine you need to filter through the ps output and lookup the name of your program. See if that works by testing it on bash.

Comment: Sorry, its the other way around. Use **ps -u** to determine the users active, and evaluate the value under **command** to determine which process they've started.